# rmagick stuck in an infinite loop that creates an image over and over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I'm using `rmagick` to create a montage. After I submit a request, it gets stuck in an infinite loop, and the request continues to create the same image over, and over, until I manually restart server:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  after_save :process

  private

  def process
    image_list = Magick::ImageList.new(*self.photos.split(','))
    montage = image_list.montage do
      self.geometry = "182x182+6+6"
      self.tile     = "4x3"
    end
    name = "#{self.id}_#{Time.now}.jpg"
    montage.write(name)
    images.build(source: File.open(name))
    save!
  end
```

Any idea why this is happening, or how to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not in `rmagick`, but due to

```
after_save :process
```

then inside `process`

```
save!
```

which creates an infinite recursion.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Duhhh... other than skipping callbacks in the save, any other options?

Comment: Perhaps use `before_save :process`, and don't then need to use `save!` in the method

Comment: I actually plan to move this into a background process, but I wanted to be sure it worked first before I did anything else.